# How can an AngularJS html page set a href to use the context path?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I was thinking in a html file to write something like:

```
<a id="homeId" class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:document.write('${pageContext.request.contextPath}')">Root Page</a>
```

In the browser what I see as the link is that actual href string not evaluated, ie:

```
javascript:document.write('${pageContext.request.contextPath}')
```

Comment: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` what is this? Is that an angularjs variable, or Jquery?

Comment: From what you are showing it looks like you are trying to run a js script from HTML if this is correct then you might want to use an event to call the function like onclick= "Function name()"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double curly braces around your variable: {{}}

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but here's a quick example that shows the variable being evaluated:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cUckEApeSLI7t4jGJcw5

Note that it just changes the value to "test".